# C# How to display all elements of array as a single number?

Tags: c#

I have a int array .

```
int[] numbers = new int[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

How can all the elements of this array displayed as a single number from last index to 0th index.In this case , it has to be 54321.

Comment: What research have you done so far on how to solve this problem, what have you tried, and what problems are you having with your solution?

Comment: No @Shaharyar , that question asks you to just print it horizontally.I am asking a way to print the number in reversed fashion.See the change in this question.

Comment: @ShubhamMarathia Yeah I missed that part. That's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 string result = string.Join("", numbers.Reverse());
```

Or even simpler:

```
string result = string.Concat(numbers.Reverse());
```

Comment: `+1` 2 of what I would consider the best single line functions in .net `.Join() and .Concat` major life savors

Comment: OP wants to reverse the sequence.

Comment: @Shaharyar and Thomas, I added `Reverse` to reverse the array.